# Excel - leading zero - duplicate values

Tags: excel

I have column A formated as Text, and I fill this data:

```
0
00
000
010
011
10
11
```

[image]

When I make conditional formatting for duplicate values it show me all value like duplicate. Problem it's cause Excel convert to number all values and then it's duplicated.

How to solve this? I try with apostrophe, but it's not working. I have try with Custom formating, but it's same.

Comment: Did you try converting them to numbers and it still shows as duplicates?

Comment: When I convert to number, then I lost leading zero, but I need them. I need 010 and 10.

Comment: You cannot solve your problem with custom formatting.  You will need to use a formula for conditional formatting in order to differentiate those values.

Answer (score 0):

Use formula in CF:

```
=SUM((A1=A:A)*(A1<>""))>1
```

[image]

Comment: I don't need help with find duplicate, I need solution that Excel don't recognized this record like a duplicate.
My problem it's why Excel recognize this records like a duplicate. How I must format data that this is not duplicate? that's is question.

Comment: @kole1108 I added an ```A8``` value to show that identical records are found as duplicates. If you use this formula for your initial values, there will be no duplicates.

Comment: But my question stil are why 010 and 10 are duplicates? How I need format 010 that they don't be duplicate with 10? I don't need solution for find duplicates, I need solution for formating 010 and 10, that they are different value. cause when I import this file into ERP, i recieve error for duplicate.

Comment: @kole1108 You cannot solve your problem with formatting.

Comment: @kole1108 If there is a problem with importing data into ERP, then you need to look at the import procedure for why you text is being converted to a number. It has nothing to do with excel.

Comment: @basic, my opinion it's opposite if Excel engine recognized 010 and 10 like 10, then when this import in ERP (and ERP use Excel engine) it's problem with duplicate value.